# Neural Network with Inner Loop

Tags: neural-networks

I want to ask if there is any type of neural network with inner feedback loops.

Yes.. I know this is not possible in ordinary neural network where you are computing all stages in one timestep but..

It could be possible if you would compute whole neural network but from right side to left side.. So basically , if the neural network has 9 layers, first result would be seen after 9 computations..  Were there any similar attempts?

Comment: How would you guarantee that computation would end in finite time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, RNN (Recurrent Neural Network) is an example of this. In RNNs, you can have connections in the "reverse" direction compared to the usual feed-forward neural networks.